# Mollification fractional Sobolev function(Convergence)

Tags: sobolev-spaces, convolution

I got a function $u\in W^{\frac{3}{2},2}((0,1),\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a standard mollifier $\eta_\epsilon$.
It follows that the mollification $u_\epsilon$ converges to $u$ in $W^{\frac{3}{2},2}((0,1),\mathbb{R}^n)$.
My problem is the semi-norm of $u'$, it is rather clear that $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $W^{1,2}((0,1),\mathbb{R}^n)$

Does anyone know a good reference to a proof?

Comment: What is the question actually? The derivatives will converge in $W^{1/2,2}$.

Comment: Why do the derivatives converge in $W^{\frac{1}{2},2}$? I need a proof but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice reference, they solved the problem in a more universal setting
https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04918
Lemma 11